# Rearranging a data frame from row id to column id

Tags: r

Lets say I have a data frame created as

```
id <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
a <- c(6,4,3,6,4,9)
b <- c(8,5,2,9,0,1)

df <- cbind.data.frame(id,a,b)
```

which gives the output as

```
   id x y
1  a 6 8
2  b 4 5
3  c 3 2
4  d 6 9
5  e 4 0
6  f 9 1
```

This is of course a smaller reproducible version of my actual problem. In my actual scenario I have created a data frame from multiple .xlsx files in the following manner

```
files <- list.files(path = "Discharge", pattern = "*_SUMQH.xls", full.names = T)

strm_data <- sapply(files, read_xlsx, simplify=FALSE) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "id")

strm_data <- as.data.frame(strm_data[,-(7:19)])
strm_data <- na.omit(strm_data)

row.names(strm_data) <- NULL
```

What I want is to arrange the data frame in the following manner

```
  id x y  id x y id x y id x y  id x y id x y
1 a  6 8  b  4 5  c 3 2 d  6 9  e  4 0  f 9 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the base R code below, using `cbind` + `split`

```
> do.call(cbind, unname(split(df, 1:nrow(df))))
  id a b id a b id a b id a b id a b id a b
1  a 6 8  b 4 5  c 3 2  d 6 9  e 4 0  f 9 1
```

Comment: Or with tidyverse `df  %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(id, a, b), names_sep = "")`

Comment: @akrun: Please provide as answer!

Comment: @TarJae thanks, but ThomasIsCoding's code is very compact and is in `base R`.  So, probably, the package solution may not be that good

Comment: @akruns: Ok. I see. thanks for clarificaiton!

Answer (score 2):

Here is really basic solution:

```
cbind(df[1,], df[2,], df[3,], df[4,], df[5,], df[6,])
```

Output:

```
  id x y id x y id x y id x y id x y id x y
1  a 6 8  b 4 5  c 3 2  d 6 9  e 4 0  f 9 1
```